# What algorithm can simplify a polygon while minimizing changed area and edge lengths?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, shapely

I would like to simplify polygons so that they look aesthetically pleasing in the following way:

[image]

- Move edges such that they have only certain inclinations like 0, 45, 90, .. degrees.
- Changes edges lengths as little as possible
- Don't add or remove vertices (only move them)

This is similar to the behavior you see in some editing tools where points snap to certain locations and angles. I am wondering if there already an algorithm for performing this and if not I was thinking maybe it can be solves as a linear or quadratic program that moves the vertices to fix the edge inclinations and tries to minimize the changes to the edge length and area of the polygon?

Comment: You did remove the vertex near the left upper corner. How does that fit with your conditions?

Comment: @Elec1 I guess that vertices that round to 180 degrees are effectively removed?

Comment: @Elec1 it's there just colinear with the previous and next one.

Comment: I haven't tested it, but the following library might give a (partial) solution or some inspiration: [orthogonalize-polygon](https://github.com/Mashin6/orthogonalize-polygon)

Comment: CGAL calls this process [Shape Regularization](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Shape_regularization/index.html).